# Proving the basic calculation rules for estimates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I always forget the proof why for example a negative number times a positive number is negative again. And the book is not very reader-friendly, i.e. it there is not a lot of prose which I would prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll prove that
$$(-a)b=-ab.$$ 
Indeed, $$(-a)b+ab=(-a+a)b=0b$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$0b=0,$$ which is true because
$$0b=(0+0)b=0b+0b$$ and from here
$$0b=0b+(-0b)=0.$$
Now, take $a>0$ and $b>0$ and you'll get the rule.